# Plotting a graph takes a long time in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

For plotting 100,000 to 500,000 data point in a text file I use the following code.
The problem is:

If I copy and paste the data points in a plotting software, reaching the plot takes just 30 seconds but with the following code it may take 1 hour or more to plot by Python.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import *
cmin=502.8571071527562
c,O=np.genfromtxt('textfile.txt',unpack=True)
for i in range(len(O)):
    q=exp(-0.5*(c[i]-cmin))
    plt.plot(O[i], q, 'bo')
plt.show()
```

What is the problem? How could I solve it?
I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some general rules:

1. use `numpy`, not `math`
2. avoid for-loops
3. Do not create unnecessary artists.

Here you want to create a single artist with all points, instead of 500000 single artists with one point each.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cmin=502.8571071527562
c,O=np.genfromtxt('textfile.txt',unpack=True)

q=np.exp(-0.5*(c-cmin))
plt.plot(O, q, 'bo')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Unless this is really strongly related the topic of this question, better ask a new question. Please also mind [ask] and [mcve] when doing so.